# Pytesseract not able to detect 3 digits number

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm currently working on a project involving digit detection in images. The original images I'm starting with are quite small, but after several preprocessing steps, I'm able to convert these to more legible images with clearer digits.

Despite this, I'm encountering a problem. My method successfully detects digits in most of my dataset. **However**, I've noticed a specific issue when the number begins with `11`. For example, with numbers like `111`, `112`, `113`... `119`, the output often incorrectly returns a single `1` or just the last digit in the number. Furthermore, for an image with the number `150`, the system strangely outputs `8`.

Could anyone provide some insight into why this might be happening, and any potential solutions to correct these inaccuracies? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

This is my code:

```py
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=5, fy=5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(2,2))
image = clahe.apply(image)
th,image = cv2.threshold(image,120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 2))
image = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image,  lang='eng', config=' digits --psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'))
```

These are my images before any preprocessing was applied to them:

Before preprocessing:

[image: 1]

After preprocessing:

[image: 2]

Result: 10

Before preprocessing:

[image: 3]

After preprocessing:

[image: 4]

Result: 8